# The meaning of "standard deviation"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the primary meaning of "standard deviation"?

Context:
There was an episode from "Everybody Loves Raymond", which was named "Standard Deviation". In short, Raymond's brother Robert was administering an IQ test for Raymond and his wife Debra. Raymond got 100 points, which according to Robert was average, and Debra scored 115 points. Roberts called that a case of standard deviation and added that that meant that Debra was in a "whole class of higher brains" as compared to Raymond.

Does it mean a deviation from a norm (which is something abnormal) or, rather, a normal deviation (which is a deviation within a normal range)?

While these two meanings seem quite possible to me in this term, they, in fact, are like direct opposites of each other!

Or is it like the actual meaning of this term can only be deduced from context?

Comment: When clarifications or details are requested, please [edit] your post to include them so that your post can be placed in a queue to be reviewed for reopening. Otherwise, it may remain closed indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Standard deviation* is a statistical term. When you calculate the mean (average) you get just a single number, but you have no idea whether it means that every sample is close to that measurement, or if it's just the middle between extremes (compare to the old parable; if you have one foot in the oven and the other in the fridge, on average you're pretty comfortable).  The standard deviation, then, adds a second measurement which indicates how much on average each sample deviates from the mean.

For example, if the mean length of adult males is 180 cm, that only tells you one thing. If you know that the standard deviation is 7 cm, you now know that the range 173-187 is "normal" and people taller or shorter than that could be called "tall" or "short", respectively. (A common rule of thumb is to call two standard deviations - in this case 14cm - remarkable, and measurements within two standard deviations from the mean just more or less normal. But how exactly to apply this also depends on the domain of the measurements.)

See also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

I guess the episode name is actually a play with this terminology; your confusion illustrates the joke.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, but closer to normal deviation.

Normal deviation is just a bell curve - 50% of the results are above the mean, 50% are below the mean. [Standard deviation is basically distance from the mean](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/quadratic-functions-and-inequalities/standard-deviation-and-normal-distribution) - is that bell curve tall and skinny (small s.d.), wide and flat (large s.d.), or in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Intelligence tests are usually constructed to have a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15 so Debra scored one standard deviation above Raymond. This gives Raymond the opportunity for a joke. It is a case of one standard deviation in the statistical sense but he may also be suggesting that his wife is abnormal in some way.

Other answers have said what standard deviation means as a statistical concept so I will not repeat that here.